# how to join two columns into single column from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

Iam trying to get the results from two columns with the same type into single column for example

```
table 
id      secId
1         2
3         1
5         1
1         4
```

i want to retrive them like that where id or secId = 1

```
id
2
3
4
5
```

i have tried inner join but it gives me 2 columns with data redundancy

Comment: Ok, so if one of the columns is a `1` you want the value from the other column?

Comment: yes, if one of them has 1 i want to retrieve the other

Comment: Why do you need this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `union` to get that

```
select id from yourTable where secId = 1
union
select secId from yourTable where id = 1
```

Use `union all` if you don't like the way `union` also does a `distinct`

Answer (score 4):

You don't need any `Join` for that, this simple query would do it

```
select if(id=1, secId, id)
  from yourTable
  where id = 1 or secId = 1;
```

You select all data that have `id` or `secId` equal to `1` then, depending on which of both is equal to `1` you display `secId` or `id`.

Assuming here only one of both value can be `1`.

If there is the possibility to have two values, then you can use the union syntax as @AndreasWederbrand described.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a [CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) statement to pick between the two columns.

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN id = 1 --if this is a 1 select the other col
            THEN secId
        ELSE id --otherwise just select this column
        END AS newCol
FROM yourTable
WHERE id = 1
    OR secId = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simplest code for that:

```
Select Case When id = 1 then secId end ID from yourtable
```